# Is "solutioning" a correct word in a technical context?

Tags: gerunds, technical

I'm a translator from English into Italian language. While translating a British patent I found the following sentence:

> The large heat treatment window seen in the ThermoCalc simulation also suggests that it [the alloy in question] will respond with full solutioning without incipient melting for the solutioning and HIP procedures associated with most base alloys when it is used as filler alloy for welding.

What do you think about "solutioning" as used here?

Comment: I don't like it at all. HIP = hot isostatic pressing? Is "solutioning" supposed to refer to the alloy's being placed in a solution or being used as a solution for solving welding problems? Tell us what it's supposed to mean and maybe someone with the proper technical background can come with a better term. "Solutioning" is ugly. I agree with Andrew Leach.

Comment: this patent was accepted? No wonder there are so many patent lawsuits.

Answer (score 5):

It appears in this context 'solutioning' is a highly specialized technical jargon used in advanced metallurgy. It denotes a process of creating a solution of metals - an atomic scale mix of materials (as opposed to a mix of bigger, coarse particles). I see it used commonly in professional, scientific papers on this subject, and I believe it is correct in this context.

(and due to the nature of the process - a compound of two solids heated but not entirely molten - classic alternatives, like dissolving, diluting, mixing etc don't convey the specific meaning.)

Of course the businesspeak of "solutioning on a problem" is a horrible, horrible abuse.

Comment: I agree with this inference, but one wonders what the difference is to alloying (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alloying) or even amalgamating....one also wonders whether 'incipient' adds anything to the sentence above.

Comment: @Merk: From the texts where I noticed the usage of this word, the metallurgist is alloying or amalgamating metals. The metals are solutioning in the process.

Answer (score 1):

OED: ‘To treat with, fasten or secure by, a solution.’ First citation dated 1891:

> A further improvement..will dispense with the need for solutioning the
>   canvas.

Comment: I don't think that's the sense being used in this example. I googled "solutioning" and "incipient melting" and it seems that solutioning seems to mean "dissolving".